# Opencart 2.2.0.0 Translation Issue

Tags: opencart2.x

I am trying to translate opencart version 2.2.0.0

I have translated the file and put them in following 2 directory

`catalog/language/bangla`

`admin/language/bangla`

it is working for category, product description etc from admin backend but not working for any of the parameters given in .php file like ' 
`$_['text_checkout']`  `$_['text_wishlist`'] etc. etc

I am testing it in localhost. Am I doing anything wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To install a language package, you have to transfer **all your files** on your server (keeping the same structure) on the roots of a previously installed OpenCart.

After that, open your OpenCart backend and follow these steps:

1. Navigate to `System -> Localisation -> Languages`
2. Click the `Add New` button
3. Fill in the following values :

   1. *Language Name* : name of the language, for example `French`
   2. *Code* : code of your language, for example `fr`
   3. *Locale* : localization of your language, for example `fr,fr-FR,fr_FR.UTF-8,french`
   4. *Image* : flag image for the language, for example `fr.png`
   5. *Directory* : directory of your language pack, for example `fr-FR`
   6. *Status* : `Enabled`
   7. *Sort Order*: `1`
4. Save these changes
5. Navigate to `System -> Settings`
6. Click on the tab `Local` and define your standard languages for frontend and backend (backend language will not change **before** this step)
7. Save these changes
8. Installation is complete

Comment: hi i did this already. only its not updating the translated parameters value like $_['text_checkout']="my language"

Comment: It seems that the untranslated values are those stored in the `default` files: did you name them correctly according to your language?
Indeed, [since version 2.0.2.0](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/2866), the `default` files must have a name related to the language.

Comment: hi I have translated all the parameters in my own language file  located in `catalog/language/bengali `and `admin/language/bengali `directory. Also i have bengali.php file in both the directory. But still no luck

Comment: Sounds strange. Are you sure you have verified the correct data, _i.e._ `ben` for bengali language and `BD` for Bangladesh for example (step 3.2 et 3.3)? Did you fill the correct path `bengali` for your folder (step 3.5)?